# Как сделать 2 массива на insert и на update в базу данных из двух других массивов

Tags: php

```
$data = [
  4 => ['id' => 2, 'url' => 'https://google.com/', 'status' => 1],
  5 => ['id' => 4, 'url' => 'https://yandex.ru/', 'status' => 1],
  7 => ['id' => 5, 'url' => 'https://mail.ru/', 'status' => 1],
  24 => ['id' => 11, 'url' => 'https://yahoo.com/', 'status' => 1],
  ...
];

$api = [
  1 => ['id' => 11, 'url' => 'https://vk.com/'],
  3 => ['id' => 21, 'url' => 'https://ok.ru/'],
  8 => ['id' => 14, 'url' => 'https://yandex.ru/'],
  17 => ['id' => 23, 'url' => 'https://facebook.com/'],
  224 => ['id' => 41, 'url' => 'https://yahoo.com/'],
  ...
];
```

`$data` - это то что хранится в базе данных

`$api` - это получение данных с внешнего источника

Нужно 2 массива, 1 - на insert, 2 - на update

`$insert` - добавляется то что нет в $data

`$update` - меняется status на 0, если в $data нет такого что в $api

То что нужно в итоге:

```
$insert = [
  0 => ['id' => 11, 'url' => 'https://vk.com/', 'status' => 1],
  1 => ['id' => 21, 'url' => 'https://ok.ru/', 'status' => 1],
  2 => ['id' => 23, 'url' => 'https://facebook.com/', 'status' => 1],
];

$update = [
  0 => ['id' => 2, 'url' => 'https://google.com/', 'status' => 0],
  1 => ['id' => 5, 'url' => 'https://mail.ru/', 'status' => 0],
];
```

И как правильно сделать SQL запрос на все это?

Comment: для начала, напишите своё решение(или неудачное решение). Задача не сильно сложная, и если вы новичок, то попробуйте сделать сами

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

$data = [
  4 => ['id' => 2, 'url' => 'https://google.com/', 'status' => 1],
  5 => ['id' => 4, 'url' => 'https://yandex.ru/', 'status' => 1],
  7 => ['id' => 5, 'url' => 'https://mail.ru/', 'status' => 1],
  24 => ['id' => 11, 'url' => 'https://yahoo.com/', 'status' => 1]
  
];

$api = [
  1 => ['id' => 11, 'url' => 'https://vk.com/'],
  3 => ['id' => 21, 'url' => 'https://ok.ru/'],
  8 => ['id' => 14, 'url' => 'https://yandex.ru/'],
  17 => ['id' => 23, 'url' => 'https://facebook.com/'],
  224 => ['id' => 41, 'url' => 'https://yahoo.com/']
  
];



foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
  # code...
//$gon[]=$value['url'];
$tyu[$value['id']]=$value['url'];

echo "<br>";

}

//print_r($tyu);
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
foreach ($api as $key1 => $value1) {
  # code...
$somn[$value1['id']]=$value1['url'];
echo "<br>";

}
$result = array_diff($tyu, $somn);

$result1 = array_diff($somn, $tyu);
print_r($result);
echo "<br>";
print_r($result1);
echo "<br>";
foreach ($result1 as $key5 => $value5) {
  
$insert[]=array('id'=>$key5, 'url'=>$value5, 'status'=>'1');


}

foreach ($result as $key4 => $value4) {
  # code...
 $upda[]=array('id'=>$key4,'url'=>$value4, 'status'=>'0');
//echo "<br>";
  //print_r($value4);
}


$conn1 = new mysqli('192.168.0.1', 'login', '***', 'namebase');


// Check connection
if ($conn1->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn1->connect_error);
} 
mysqli_set_charset($conn1,"utf8");


foreach ($upda as $k => $val) {
  # code...


$query1 = "UPDATE nametable SET id='".$val['id']."', url = '".$val['url']."', status = '".$val['status']."'";

if (mysqli_query($conn1, $query1)) {

//echo "<br>"."ok"."<br>";
  }else{
    echo "Oshibka".mysqli_error($conn1);
  }


}

foreach ($insert as $ke => $valu) {
  # code...


$query10 = "INSERT INTO nametable1 (id, url, status) VALUES ( '".$valu['id']."','".$valu['url']."','".$valu['status']."' )";

if (mysqli_query($conn1, $query10)) {

//echo "<br>"."ok";
  }else{
    echo "Oshibka".mysqli_error($conn1);
  }

}


?>
```